# Sending pictures

Tags: discussion

Does Home Improvment have directions for sending in pictures? I’ve tried to find something giving direction but having no luck, thanks Oily Tex

Comment: It's all right there in the editor if you'll only take a moment to look at it.

Comment: I think what may be missing from the answer to that dup question is to explicitly tell the user that they must 'edit' their original question, and not try to post pictures (or any additional info) in the comments. Many new users who are more used to traditional 'forum' sites don't seem to be aware of this.

Comment: WOW, thanks to all for the quick feedback. I will explore edit further and sure I will get some results, This site is fantastic, learning so much, but can be intimidating to a ( new-be )

Comment: brhans; thanks so much, but I hit the picture button & got a message that my image is “” too large to up load over 2 MB “” so guess I can’t send any, but your comment about editing picture in the original question helped me, because I would of tried to send it in the comments section, thanks Oily Tex

Comment: You could probably upload your pic to [imgur](https://imgur.com/) first, and then edit it into your question by providing a link to it on imgur ... or reduce the size of your image first.